# Jest mock factory functions from named exports

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs

I want to mock this so I only mock the get() return method from Bar so when Foo calls find(), get() is mocked and returned.

Bar file

```
// bar file
function Bar(){
  function get(){
    //...
  }
  return {
    get
  }
}
export default Bar;
```

Foo file

```
// foo file
import Bar from './bar';
function Foo(func){
  const bar = Bar();
  function find(){
    bar.get();
  }
  return {
    find,
  };
}
export default Foo
```

Index.js

```
// index.js
import Bar from './bar';
import Foo from './foo';
export {Bar, Foo};
```

My test

```
//foo test
import {Bar, Foo} from './index'

//This mocks everything
jest.mock('./index');

// This will say Cannot find module Bar
jest.mock('Bar', () => ({
  get: () => jest.fn().mockReturnValue('test'),
}));
    
describe('test foo', ()=> {
  let foor = Foo();
  foo.find();
})
```

I tried mocking Bar itself it says "Cannot find module Bar"

How can I mock Bar, a factory function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming you have put the `foo.js`, `bar.js` in folder eg:'common' and having `index.js` file as follows, you can write in this way.
since we want to mock the `Bar` as per your added code snippet it should return a `function` which upon called returns an `object` that has `get` property having the value of `function`. make sure that while mocking, since it is not any third party libraries give relative path of the file which we are mocking in this case it is `./common/bar`

```
  //bar.js
    function Bar(){
        function get(){}
        return {
          get
        }
      }
    
    export default Bar;
    
    //foo.js
    import Bar from './bar';
    
    function Foo(func){
      const bar = Bar();
      function find(){
        return bar.get(); //Note the return 
      }
      return {
        find,
      };
    }
    export default Foo
    
    //index.js
    import Bar from './bar';
    import Foo from './foo';
    export {Bar, Foo};
    
    //app.test.js
    import { Foo } from './common'
    
    jest.mock('./common/bar', () => (function(){
      return(
        {
          get: jest.fn().mockReturnValue('test') //Note this
        }
      )
    }));
        
    describe("Foo function", () => {
      it("Should call and return correct value", () => {
        let foor = Foo();
        expect(foor.find()).toEqual("test");
      });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, it appears I was returning an object instead of a function. Cheers.